# Razor Missing Closing Brace / Tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my View Razor is telling me that my Foreach Loop is missing a closing Brace (`}`) 
   It is also telling me my `<div class="row">` is missing its closing tag.

```
 @{int spanCounter = 0;}
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
     if(spanCounter == 0)
     {
        <div class="row">
     }
     spanCounter += item.Span;

     <div class="span@(item.Span)">
       @item.Html
     </div>

     @if(spanCounter == 12)
     {
       @spanCounter = 0

       </div>
     }    
 }
```

I have seen similar question but they seem to focus on the fact that Razor expects to be properly hierarchical. ie, this is illegal:

```
if(condition)
{
    <foo>
}
else
{
    <foo>
}
</foo>
```

**UPDATE**
The Model is a List of Html Content "Blocks"

To be a little clearer I want to write out a mulitple blocks (`<div></div>`)  IN a `<div></div>` "row"

1. If the spanCounter is 0 BEGIN row.
2. Write Content: `<div></div>` blocks untill max span width is reached (12)
3. End Row, Reset counter, Go Back to 1.

Comment: I think you already know the answer.

Comment: If I did i would have answered my own question. I have many things better to do than ask question I already know the answer too ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The closing braces of my C# code are not recognized in a Razor partial view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516298/the-closing-braces-of-my-c-sharp-code-are-not-recognized-in-a-razor-partial-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it like this

```
@{int spanCounter = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  if (spanCounter == 0 || spanCounter == 12)
  {
  <div class="row">
  @spanCounter += @item.Span;
  <div class="span@(item.Span)">
      @item.Html
  </div>
  </div>
  }
  else
  {
    spanCounter += item.Span;
  <div class="span(@item.Span)">
  @item.Html
  </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are another work around that avoid repeat code:

```
if(condition)
{
    @:<foo>
}
else
{
    @:<foo>
}
</foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address your code per se but it relates to Razor's confusion with the closing brace so I'm putting it here in case anyone's really stumped like I was. With VS 2012, Razor  got confused and I finally narrowed it down an apostrophe in a comment, like this. Note how the closing brace isn't yellow:

[image]

But if you omit the apostrophe from the comment, it works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were getting this error is that the closing tag was being conditionally rendered, therefore you could not guarantee that it would be added to the view:

The spanCounter variable is being incremented here:

```
    spanCounter += item.Span;

    <div class="span@(item.Span)">
       @item.Html
    </div>
```

therefore, you cannot guarantee that it will meet the condition of this if statement i.e. it might be greater that 12 by this point:

```
    @if(spanCounter == 12)
    {
       </div>
    }
```

You need to provide full mark up for elements that are being conditionally rendered. You need something like:

```
var spanCounter = 0;
<div class="row">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    spanCounter += item.Span;
    <div class="span@(item.Span)">
        @item.Html
    </div>
   if(spanCounter == 12)
   {
       spanCounter = 0;
   }
}

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer - I knida figured that is why Razor throws the exception, but how do you work around this?

Comment: It doesn't look like this will work I am afraid, you will write a ROW for EVERY item while the span counter is less than 13, So I can only ever have one row of item(s)

Comment: Sorry Declan- in this case only one row would ever be written with the potential for content to overflow the row - hence the need for multiple rows. Thanks

Comment: I now see what you are trying to do: display the items in rows of 12